# How to calculate difference of date using sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to extract the last 7 days total number of requests from my table named "Request". It has fields Date and Time and other records as well. Following is my piece of code:

```
 public void TotalRequest()
    {
        DateTime d1=DateTime.Now;
        DateTime d2=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
        TimeSpan t=d1-d2;
        double days=t.TotalDays;
        SqlConnection MySQL = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
        string total_req = "select count(*) from Request where Date>='" + days + "'";
        SqlCommand com=new SqlCommand(total_req,MySQL);
        MySQL.Open();
        int Total_Requests = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        MySQL.Close();
        Response.Write(Total_Requests.ToString());
    }
```

The error is "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.". Please guide and thanks in advance for your valuable time.

Comment: Please look into SQL Parameters.

Comment: which parameter? talking about Total_Requests value?

Comment: i think what you want to do is something like where Date>= d2.toString() because Date is a type of date probably

Comment: @btevfik yes I did it by just using d2.ToString(). Thanks for support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a type of Date to your sql because it cannot convert 'days'.
You already have d2 as 7 days earlier from now so do this.

```
string total_req = "select count(*) from Request where Date>='" + d2.ToString() + "'";
```